# Read all Section from INI file and add into a list delphi

Tags: delphi, ini

I'm trying to take the section from an Ini file and add it into a list then ultimately, add the list to a ComboBox. I found how to add the values of the Section but I cannot find how to just retrieve the Section. For example, I want just the city names from below:

[Toronto]
population: 10

[Vancouver]
population: 4

Then my List would by [Toronto, Vancouver]. Seems like all the IniFile.Read* just reads the keys and not the section. Any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: By the way, key-value pairs ini INI files are separated by ``=``!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `TIniFile.ReadAllSections` to retrieve the name of all sections into a `TStrings` descendant, which could be the `ComboBox.Items`.

```
ComboBox1.Items.Clear;
Ini.ReadAllSections(ComboBox1.Items);
```